# How to check number of http connections used at a specific point in time?

Tags: java, vert.x

I have project with vertx where I am using a `HtttpClient` where I configurure a `HttpConfigOption` object in order to specify host, maxPoolSize, keepAlive, etc.

```
  HttpClientOptions httpClientOptions = new HttpClientOptions()
                        .setKeepAlive(KeepAlive)
                        .setDefaultHost(baseUrl)
                        .setTcpNoDelay(true)
                        .setVerifyHost(verifyHost)
                        .setTrustAll(trustAll)
                        .setMaxPoolSize(50)
                        .setPoolCleanerPeriod(POOL_CLEANER_PERIOD)
                        .setDefaultPort(port).setSsl(isSSl);
```

I start having some timeouts and I want to know if the problem is from my connection pool or the timeouts are coming from the services that I consume.

Is there a way to print in `vertx` the number of connections that are at the moment in use? So for example let's say that I have a poll with max 50 connections and on timeout it will be nice if I can print the number of connections that are active, in use.

Thanks

Comment: Let's say all of your connections are in use, would that indicate a problem with your pool size or your services being slow? Wouldn't it make sense to keep track of the service response times anyway to be able to determine whether they are fast enough?

Comment: @Thomas I know what you say but I don't have any control on the partner api's(they are a few that I integrate with). That's why I was thinking if I can see this info maybe I can understand more on when and why is happening and on some point to increase the pool with a relevant number

Comment: You should always be able to track time on the call/client level. And you might want to set timeouts on those API calls.

Comment: I have timeouts on API calls. The problem is that I can not distinguish between when I get a timeout from the client or the timeout appears because the connection pool can not offer other. Also the response time is different from client to client and from endpoint to endpoint and it will be quite hard to interpret all this data. PS. Thanks for taking time and writing

Comment: Well, analyzing what's goig on will take time, that's right. However, if you use a correlation id to trace what your system is doing you should see whether and where processing is slow. You'd need that analysis anyway to know what a reasonable pool size would be, what the frequency and processing time of your requests is etc. - Also, Vert.x is built to accept _a lot_ of requests and process them in a non-blocking way. All this indicates you're having a problem with processing speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vertx micrometer module to grab  `vertx_http_client_active_connections`

ref: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-micrometer-metrics/java/